# How to pass a file from a URL via Python to an API?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use an API where you give it a CSV file and it validates it.  For this API you pass it a file.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
import requests
import urllib3

api_url="https://validation.openbridge.io/dryrun"
file_url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'


http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', file_url)
data = response.data.decode('utf-8')



headers = {
#     requests won't add a boundary if this header is set when you pass files=
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, files=data)
```

I'm getting an error I don't quite understand:

> 'cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples'

I'm fairly new to python, I'm mostly experienced in other languages but what I think the issue is that I'm probably passing the API the data in the file instead of giving it the file.

Any suggestions on what I"m doing wrong and how I can pass that file to the API?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this off google in the future.  I figured out how to do it.

```
import requests
import urllib3

api_url="https://validation.openbridge.io/dryrun"
file_url="http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv"

remote_file = urllib3.PoolManager().request('GET', file_url)

response = requests.post(url=api_url,
                             json={'data': {'attributes': {'is_async': True }}}, 
                             files={ "file": remote_file}, 
                             allow_redirects=False)

if response.ok:
    print("Upload completed successfully!")
    print()
    print("Status Code: ")
    print(response.status_code)
    print()
    print(response.headers['Location'])
    print()
else:
    print("Something went wrong!")
    print()
    print("Status Code: ")
    print(response.status_code)
    print()
    print(response.text)
    print()
```